# What departments in a university could want a volunteer pure math alumni during the summer?

Tags: career-path, university, canada

I am looking for academic opportunities in the summer. Tomorrow I am going in person to ask professors in the math department. An engineering PhD candidate told me that there may be other departments I could investigate. They stated engineering as an example, but didn't give me what kind of engineering I should be looking in. Something like that would be useful.

I wish to become a professor, so summer opportunities would provide great exposure as well as a boost to next years graduate school application.

I apologize if I did anything wrong when posting this (I don't know the website that well) and hope you have a good day :)

Comment: Your post implies, but doesn't state that you have a bachelor's in pure math, is that correct?

Comment: Did you apply to the various internships opportunities that all universities have?

Answer (score 1):

If asking in a math department, I would not look for "volunteers" or "opportunities".

Instead, I'd identify something specific you'd like to accomplish, and ask for help with that. You might, if you're lucky, find someone willing to supervise a summer reading or research project. Identify a topic or two of interest, do a bit of background reading first, think about what you'd like to achieve, and only then approach faculty members.

If you have difficulty deciding on your goals in general, you might try to meet with student services-oriented staff members, who might be better equipped than individual faculty researchers. Nobody is going to tell you what department to approach, you have to decide for yourself what you find most interesting.

Good luck!